# I want to append file data into formBuilder object How to do Help me

Tags: angular

there is form I want to add my image file data as array to formBuilder object

```
this.formData = new FormGroup({
    name    : new FormControl(),
    city    : new FormControl(),
    image : new FormControl()
});

onFileSelected(event) {
    this.fileData = <File>event.target.files[0];
}

onSubmit(){ 
    console.log("FILE DATA ",this.fileData);
    this.formData.image= this.fileData;
    console.log(this.formData.image);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please explain what issue you are facing when getting the image data. So that we can help you to solve your problem.

Comment: also share the related HTML part or StackBlitz demo is possible

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do in my Angular Projects.

This is the Component's TS file

```js
// ...
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  myFile: File;

  myForm = new FormGroup ({
    name: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
  });

  // The ApiService
  constructor(private api: ApiService) {
  }

// ...

  handleFileInput(files: FileList) {
    this.myFile = files.item(0);
  }

  submitForm() {
    this.api.submitMyForm(this.myFile, this.myForm.value).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        // Handle Response
      }
  }

}
```

This is the HTML

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()"  >
  <section class="form-block">
     <div class="form-group">
        <label class="required" for="name">Your Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" formControlName="name" >
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
        <label class="required" for="file">Your File</label>
        <input type="file" id="file" (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)">
     </div>
  </section>
</form>
```

And now for the magic, in the ApiService TS file

```js
export class ApiService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  submitMyForm(file, data) {
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('myFile', file, file.name);
    for (const key in data) {
      if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        const element = data[key];
        formData.append(key, element);
      }
    }
    return this.http.post(YOUR_API_URL, formData);
  }

}
```

That's it done.